# How can I store user data on their Google drive account by using Google drive SDK in android?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I tried to store data but it authorize only my account. Please help guys, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at this https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started ?

Comment: yeah I completed android quick start demo application from there.

Comment: Is your account the one that is installed on the testing device?  Try an emulator with a test gmail account.